# How can I get this loop's information in a table (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, loops, datatables

I'm trying to get the loop that is in the code after this text to have the information outputted into a table. To explain this further, the function `function doEvens()` creates a loop that takes uses the number a person enters into the input text box `Type in your Number: <input type="number" id="num">`, and displays all even numbers between that number and 2 within a paragraph:  `<p id="space"></p>`, when the numbers are displayed within the paragraph they have a semicolon and a space separating them, instead of that I would like the numbers to be within a table, I have tried using createElementById and with no luck, I have tried putting a table between certain areas of the code, with no luck I still have not been able to fix this, I have many other projects I am working on and I am not very good at coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function doEvens() {
            var number = document.getElementById('num').value;
            if(number > 1) {
                if(number % 2 == 0) {
                    while(number > 2) {
                        document.getElementById("space").innerHTML += (+number - 2) + "; ";
                        number = +number - 2;
                    }
                } else {
                    number--;
                    alert(number);
                    while(number > 1) {
                        document.getElementById("space").innerHTML += (+number - 2) + "; ";
                        number = +number - 2;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Type in your Number: <input type="number" id="num">
    <button onclick="doEvens();" href="javascript;">Submit</button>
    <p id="space"></p>
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A table with how many rows and cells? 
Also buttons do not have hrefs.

Comment: I don't think you need to play around with `createElement` (I assume that is what you meant). The simplest way to do this would be to replace the `p` element with a table and a row, and adding `td` tags between the numbers in your `innerHTML` assignments. Not the most sophisticated table, but still a table -- perhaps a list would be better here.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the solution with `table`. Here it is:

```js
function doEvens() {
  var number = document.getElementById('num').value,
    table = document.getElementById('evensTable'),
    cellsInRow = 20,
    evens = [],
    tableContent = '',
    row = '',
    i = 3, 
    startAt,
    numberOfRows;

  table.innerHTML = '';

  while (i++ < number - 1) {
    i % 2 === 0 && evens.push(i);
  }

  numberOfRows = evens.length / 20;

  for (var r = 0; r < numberOfRows; r++) {
    row = '<tr>';
    startAt = r * cellsInRow;
    
    for (var c = startAt; c < startAt + cellsInRow; c++) {
      if (!evens[c]) break;

      row += '<td>' + evens[c] + '</td>';
    }
    
    row += '</tr>';
    tableContent += row;
  }
  
  table.innerHTML = tableContent;
}
```

```html
<body>
  Type in your Number:
  <input type="number" id="num">
  <button onclick="doEvens();" href="javascript;">Submit</button>
  <table id="evensTable">
  </table>
</body>
```

This `table` contains one row, but you can also create more rows in code (say after every 10 numbers print)

If something is not clear for you, please ask me.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the solution as per your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand the code you have given me but I am a bit confused on how I would go about creating more rows, say after maybe 20 numbers?

Comment: Thanks so much you have been an amazing help!

Comment: I have updated the solution, please check it out and ask me if something is not clear for you.